# Negative lookbehind with optional suffix without duplication

Tags: regex

I am writing regex that finds all stings with these conditions:

- not starting with `foo/` or `bar/` or with `foo` (end of line) or `bar` (end of line)
- not ending with `/baz` or `/qux` and not ending with `/baz/` or `/qux/`

Examples that should not match:

```
foo
bar/nomatch
/nomatch/baz
nomatch/baz/
```

Examples should match:

```
foomatch
bazmatch
/baz/match
```

The regex I came up with combines a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind:

```
/(?!(foo|bar)(\/|$)).*(?<!(\/)(baz|qux)(\/|$))/gm
```

**My problem**: the negative lookbehind needs to have a fixed width (ie: I cannot use `(\/|$)` to check for an optional slash at the end of the string). I could solve this by creating the following rule: `/(?!(foo|bar)(\/|$)).*(?<!(\/)(baz|qux))(?<!(\/)(baz|qux)\/)/gm`, which uses `baz` and `qux` twice. Is there another way to solve this without this duplication?

For an interactive example, see: https://regex101.com/r/bIosD0/1

Comment: Try `^(?!foo\/|bar\/)(?!.*(?:foo|bar)$)(?!.*\/(?:baz|qux)\/?$).*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkUamZ/1).

Comment: This does technically answer the question, but now you have `foo` and `bar` duplicated instead, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber From your regex it doesn't seem you're searching for something "not ending with `foo` or `bar`" as your requirement imposes.

Comment: In PCRE: `^(?!(foo|bar)\/)(?!.*(?1)$)(?!.*\/(?:baz|qux)\/?$).*` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkUamZ/2).

Comment: you are right, I have updated this it should not start with foo + end of line or bar + end of line.

Comment: Then Wiktor's regex simply becomes `^(?!(foo|bar)(\/|$))(?!.*\/(?:baz|qux)\/?$).*`.

Comment: Maybe [`^(?!(?:foo|bar)(?:\/|$)|(?:.*\/)?(?:baz|qux)\/?$).+`](https://regex101.com/r/rh2cnE/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *drop the lookbehind* and either add another negative look*ahead* or use one and [alternate](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside between different conditions. Assuming you also want to disallow `qux` and `baz` alone.

```
^(?!(?:foo|bar)(?:\/|$)|(?:.*\/)?(?:baz|qux)\/?$).+
```

At [`^` start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the `(?!` *negative* [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `)` contains two conditions:

1. `(?:foo|bar)(?:\/|$)` what you got already, e.g. *no* `foo/...`, `foo` (same for `bar`)
2. `|(?:.*\/)?(?:baz|qux)\/?$` [OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) *no* `baz`, `baz/` preceded by an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `.*\/` ([any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) followed by a slash) to further disallow such as `.../baz/`, `.../baz` at `$` *end*.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rh2cnE/1)

I used `(?:` [non-capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) `)` for alternations because nothing needs to be captured.